# Unity Input System Rebinding freezes game while waiting for new key press

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am coding a VR game in Unity. I am implementing a keybind system that allows the player to rebind certain actions in the menu. The rebinding is functional, however, while waiting for the new key to be pressed, the game freezes (the VR view stays the same even when looking around, which makes the VR headset feel very unresponsive).

Here is the rebinding code:

```
public void Rebind(string _actionName, Button _pressedButton)
    {
        
        InputAction _toBeRebound = currentPlayerInput.currentActionMap[_actionName];
        _toBeRebound.PerformInteractiveRebinding().OnComplete
        (
            _callback =>
            {
                _pressedButton.GetComponentInChildren<TMP_Text>().text = _callback.action.bindings[0].effectivePath;
                Debug.Log("rebound successfully");
                _callback.Dispose(); //avoid memory leak
            }
        ).Start();

        SaveKeybinds();
    }
```

How can I stop the game from freezing while the new key press is being awaited? Any responses are appreciated and I would be happy to share any other necessary details.

Comment: In general shouldn't the `SaveKeybinds();` rather go inside the `OnComplete` callback?

Comment: I made this change, but it did not fix the problem. I agree it is a better place to put the call.

Comment: No of course not .. I don't think there is another non-blocking way except implementing the bind yourself and don't use interactive rebinding

Comment: Alright, thank you for your input. I will implement my own rebinding solution.